# Intel VTune Sampling after certain period of time

Tags: windows, intel, sample, sampling, intel-vtune

I am new to VTune and was playing around with it. One thing that I was not able to figure out was how do I get multiple samples of the events after every 20 seconds and save them in a text file.

For example, run an application using VTune and get back the general exploration results every 20 seconds for 2 minutes. Which means, I should have 6 samples of the events at the end.

Comment: Did you try to increase "sampling interval"? Further details depend on your usage model: do you use GUI or command line? What exact interval you really want (20 seconds is too long)?

Comment: I use a GUI for now. But I have also used the command line.

Comment: Something like take samples after every 10,000 instructions. Is that possible through VTune ?

Comment: Every 10 000 instructions is impossible via VTune user interface. Sampling every 100 millisecons or every 900 milliseconds IS possible.   To do sampling every 900 milliseconds - do following: New Analysis > Look at upper central part of the screen > Look at "CPU sampling interval, ms" combo-box and override default value. This works for all analysis types, including basic hotspots analysis type.

Comment: Thanks for the above answer. Is it possible to do the sample after 10,000 instructions using the VTune command line ?